# handling exception while converting to double in c++

Tags: c++, file, exception

I am reading data from text file and there is double value which i need to read from the file. Now the problem is that if the double value is invalid for example "!@#$%^&*" then i want my program to give exception so i can handle it. This is my code

```
void Employee::read(istream &is) {
    try{

        is.get(name, 30);
        is >> salary;
        char c;

        while(is.peek()=='\n')
            is.get( c ); 

    }
    catch(exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try inputting it to a string and using `stod` if you have C++11. That would throw an `std::invalid_argument` exception.

Comment: I finally made it work by setting exception bit on for istream 
`is.exceptions(ios::failbit | ios::badbit); //setting ifstream to throw exception on bad data`

Comment: Interesting, I never knew you could do that. You can post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work by setting exception bit on for istream

```
is.exceptions(ios::failbit | ios::badbit);  //setting ifstream to throw exception on bad data
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a runnable example of validating **double** input.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<limits>
using std::numeric_limits;
int main(){
    std::string goodString = "12.212", badString = "!@$&*@"; 
    std::istringstream good(goodString), bad(badString);
    double d1=numeric_limits<double>::min(),
           d2=numeric_limits<double>::min();
    std::string tmp;
    
    good >> d1;
    if (d1 == numeric_limits<double>::min()) {
      // extraction failed
      d1 = 0;
      good.clear(); // clear error flags to allow further extraction
      good >> tmp; // consume the troublesome token
      std::cout << "Bad on d1\n";
    } else std::cout << "All good on d1\n";
    
    if (d2 == numeric_limits<double>::min()) {
      d2 = 0;
      bad.clear();
      bad >> tmp;
      std::cout << "Bad on d2\n";
    } else std::cout << "All good on d2\n";
}
```

The output produced is..

> All good on d1
>
> Bad on d2